# How to chain filter and map methods in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, method-chaining

So I'm working on a project where I'm making a call to a database to retrieve the data stored there. This data comes as an array. here is the code:

```
  const allLogins = await Login.find().sort("name");

  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  const user = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtPrivateKey"));

  const logins = allLogins
    .filter((login) => login.userId === user._id)
    .map((login) => {
      login.password = decrypt(login.password);
    });
```

If I call a console.log after the decrypt has been run I see that it has been completed correctly. The issue I have is if I console.log(logins) it says it is an array of two items that are both undefined. If instead I run it like this...

```
  const allLogins = await Login.find().sort("name");

  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  const user = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtPrivateKey"));

  let logins = allLogins.filter((login) => login.userId === user._id);
    
  logins.map((login) => {
      login.password = decrypt(login.password);
    });
```

Then it works as it should. I'm not sure why the first set of code doesn't work and why the second set does work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In both these code samples the `.map()` does not `return` anything (it is supposed to `return`). Either add an explicit `return` statement like this: `const logins = allLogins.filter(....).map(login => { return decrypt(login.password); });`. Or, if you prefer using de-structuring, try this: `const logins = allLogins.filter(....).map(({ password }) => decrypt(password));`. There is no explicit return. Note that both of these do not mutate the `login` iterator/object.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing any of this. Instead of loading all logins from the database into your app, simply start with `const [login] = await Login.find({userId: user._id});` (or something like that, check your ORM documentation on how to fetch an object by id).

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the helpful comments! I was able to make my code cleaner and more efficient thanks to you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic :

- array. filter - accept a callback and call back return boolean (that match our criteria)
- array.map     - accept a callback and call back return transformed object

In the second working example:

```
logins.map((login) => { 
   // note: logins is iterated but not assigned to logins back
   // so accessing login is working
   login.password = decrypt(login.password); // map should return data
 + return login; // if we update all code will work
});
```

Now coming to first example:

```
const logins = allLogins
     .filter((login) => login.userId === user._id)
     .map((login) => {
      login.password = decrypt(login.password);
      + return login; // this will fix the issue 
    });
```